# verilog testbench(with for loop) for 3-8 decoder signal value not updating

Tags: verilog

I'm new to verilog. I write a 3-8 decoder and a testbench for it. This is `38_decoder_tb.v`:

```
module decoder_38(input [2:0] in, output reg [7:0] out);
always @* begin
  case (in) //Switch based on concatenation of control signals
    3'b000 : out = 8'b00000001;
    3'b001 : out = 8'b00000010;
    3'b010 : out = 8'b00000100;
    3'b011 : out = 8'b00001000;
    3'b100 : out = 8'b00010000;
    3'b101 : out = 8'b00100000;
    3'b110 : out = 8'b01000000;
    3'b111 : out = 8'b10000000;
  endcase
end
endmodule
```

This is `38_decoder_tb.v`:

```
`timescale  1ns / 1ns

module tb_decoder_38;

// decoder_38 Parameters
parameter PERIOD  = 20;

// decoder_38 Inputs
reg   [2:0]  in                           ;

// decoder_38 Outputs
wire  [7:0]  out                           ;  
reg clk;
integer i;


initial
begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #(PERIOD/2)  clk=~clk;
end

decoder_38  u_decoder_38 (
    .in                      ( in   [2:0] ),

    .out                     ( out  [7:0] )
);

initial
begin
in = 0;
#(PERIOD*2);
    for (i = 3'd0; i < 3'd8; i=i+1) begin
    in = i;
   #PERIOD;     
    end
end

endmodule
```

I stimulate the testbench module with ModelSim 10.5. As you can see, the signal just doesn't update. What's the problem? Does it have something to do with the for loop?

[image]

Comment: 3'd8 exceeds 3 bits. This will be treated as 0. You may change this to 8.

Comment: @sharvian Thank you. After I fix this mistake, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @sharvian Sorry, I made a mistake. I only recompiled the testbench file, so the wave didn't change. But if I compile all, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the issue is with the loop.

Your problem is in definition of `3'd8`. `8` is the same as `1000` in binary presentation and requires 4 bits. Therefore, 3-bits of it (as you requested) yield `000`. As a result your loop does not run at all, looking like the following: *for (i = 3'd0; i < 0; i++)*.

Variable `i` is defined as `integer`. An `integer` type is a *4-state data type, `32`-bit signed integer*. So, rewriting loop as `for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)` will solve your issues.  There is absolutely no need to define sizes for the constants in this loop.

And, to avoid infinite loop, you need to use $finish when appropriate, as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: Thank you. `for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)` is the solution. But if I add `$finish`,  modelsim will just exit.

Answer (score 1):

The posted testbench has an infinite loop because of the forever loop with nothing to stop it.
I added a #30 delay to see the last clock of data, and $finish to stop it.
After that the code behaves as expected.
All 4 simulators on EDA Playground show the same.

```
initial
begin
in = 0;
#(PERIOD*2);
  for (i = 3'd0; i <= 3'd7; i=i+1) begin
    in = i;
    #PERIOD;     
  end
  //
  #30;
  $finish;
end
```

[image]

Here is a link playground I put together https://www.edaplayground.com/x/aZYL

Comment: Thank you. Your code works fine. But if I add `$finish`, modelsim will just exit. I guess that modelsim is different from iverilog.